# Baking procedural textures not working completely

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor, procedural

So I am trying to export this model that uses procedural textures to a game engine so I have been trying to bake emission textures for the diffuse but for some reason some of the textures bake as just solid black. More weirdly as is most clear in the second screenshot one of the textures baked a couple stripes that seem normal but nothing across the rest of the texture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your node tree is incorrect: RGB sockets (yellow) can't be directly plugged to shader sockets (green). So, firstly, use proper shaders.

Comment: @SergeL It doesn't show very well in the screenshot but it works perfectly fine for some textures that have rgb plugged into the shader, I'm only looking to bake the rgb anyways. I tried baking the wooden base plugging the rgb into an emission before the material output but it has the same weird stripe thing happening